# Error loading widget related to Android updates / SDK updates?

Tags: android, widget

I have an app that works fine in the past in Android 4.3 to Android 6. Recently I have updated the Android Studio, yet, I keep the target and compilation sdk at 21. My app comes with a widget.

Now, I want to install the app to Android 7.0+. I found that every time if I just install without reboot, the widget will show "Problem loading widget". If I uninstall it, reboot the device, and then install, the widget works fine. I have test 2 mobile phone and 1 tablet. All behave the same way. Logcat did not show any error. I have not modify any code and the behaviour becomes like this.

Any idea? Will it related to some updates of the Android Studio or related sdks etc? I have updated the build.gradle to the latest one.

Comment: Hi, Did you find solution to your problem. I'm also facing similar issue.

Comment: No. It happens sometimes and I cannot reproduce. It is like random. However, I found that rebooting always can solve the problem. It seems to be memory problem? I still cannot figure out.

Comment: Yeah, rebooting always solves it. Also if you remove and re-add widget for like 3-4 times, it also fixes it.

Comment: It also depends on the Android device. I have a Samsung Tablet, no problem at all. While there is another device that always happened.

Comment: Yeah, actually it is related to OS Launcher. Mine is Pixel and Nokia, both have stock android 8.1.

Comment: One thing you may consider. My widget originally has quite a number of graphics. That causes the error. When i downsized the graphics, and reduce the number of graphics. The problem frequency decreased.

Comment: I don't think it is related. Because I even created a new widget from android studio wizard. That only has textView, but same result. :(

Comment: I want to ask one more thing, what are you using to update the widget. I want to update my widget on screen_on event, but it is not working 100% of the times in android Oreo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174382/discussion-between-user6539552-and-muhammad-mehdi-raza).